# How to skip key without value in one line for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to save some space in my code, so I wrote this simple oneline for loop. from dictionary that was k:[v,v] I am creating dictionary where the first value is key and second value stays value. Now I got an exception in my dictionary that the original dictionary has only one value, the first one.

```
glyphs_dict = {'dotaccent': [103, 86], 'ring': [104], 'caron': [105, 85]}
id_dict = {k:v for k,v in list(glyphs_dict.values())}
```

I have tried to do something like

```
id_dict = {k:v for k,v in list(glyphs_dict.values()) if k and v}
```

but doesn't work. How do I skip keys that have only one value in their list?

Comment: Wrong method. Use `.items()`. No need for `list(...)` either.

Comment: not sure what your real question is, but it should probably be `{k:v for k,v in glyphs_dict.items()}`...

Comment: well my question is that I have an exception that I want to skip, it's when one value appears in the dictionary. I don't think that any of these suggestions solves it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
id_dict = {v[0]:v[1] for v in glyphs_dict.values() if len(v) == 2}
```

this will get all values of the dict as new key and value if the length is 2 (for **key** and **value**)

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare numeric values, use `==`

Comment: That looks like a correct answer if you really want to "save some space in my code". But instead of creating unintelligible oneliners like this, I would go for code readability and cleanliness.

Comment: Thanks!! This works perfectly, I need to point out that others in comments mentioned that converting glyphs_dict.values() into list is not needed

Answer (score 1):

this also works:

```
glyphs_dict = {'dotaccent': [103, 86], 'ring': [104], 'caron': [105, 85]}
id_dict = {k: v[0] for k, *v in glyphs_dict.values() if v}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make sure to add in dict if values are more than 1

```
id_dict = {key:value for key,value in glyphs_dict.items() if len(value)>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return no errors

```
id_dict = {k:v for k,v in list(glyphs_dict.values())}
```

output:

```
{'dotaccent': [103, 86], 'ring': [104], 'caron': [105, 85]}
```

This will skip the values with lists whith one value, accepting only lists with 2

```
gid_dict = {k:v for k,v in list(glyphs_dict.items()) if len(v)==2}
```

output:

```
{'dotaccent': [103, 86], 'caron': [105, 85]}
```